# Push object in mongoDB array of objects which contains value from parent document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have a mongodb document

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "balance": 10,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "balance": 10,
      "transaction_amount": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add another object inside of transactions array and that object uses previous balance and adds the newer value.
For eg, transaction amount is 20
the document should be updated in this way

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "balance": 30,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "balance": 10,
      "transaction_amount": 10
    },
    {
      "balance": 30,
      "transaction_amount": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Now if I want to add one more document in transactions array with transaction_amount as 5 the resultant document becomes

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "balance": 35,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "balance": 10,
      "transaction_amount": 10
    },
    {
      "balance": 30,
      "transaction_amount": 20
    },
    {
      "balance": 35,
      "transaction_amount": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to do this using aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `$add` and `$concatArrays` to wrangle the data

```js
db.collection.update({
  id: 1
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "txnAmt": <amount you want>
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      balance: {
        $add: [
          "$balance",
          "$txnAmt"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "transactions": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$transactions",
          [
            {
              balance: "$balance",
              transaction_amount: "$txnAmt"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "txnAmt"
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lc9URBbVOvy) for your reference.